# Using SQL to get unsubscribed contacts from journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sql

I am attempting to pull in people who have unsubscribed from a Journey Builder Email Activity.

Is there anything in my query that will cause the following error in query studio?

***Query failed during execution. Error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'xxx@xxx.co.uk' to data type int.***

```
SELECT
  s.SubscriberKey as EMAIL_ADDRESS
, s.jobid
, s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
, sub.EmailAddress
, j.EmailName
, j2.JourneyName
, j2.VersionNumber
FROM _Sent s 
join _Job j on s.jobid = j.jobid
join _Subscribers sub on s.SubscriberKey = sub.SubscriberID
join _JourneyActivity j1 on j1.JourneyActivityObjectID = s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID 
join _Journey j2 on j2.VersionID = j1.VersionID
WHERE j.EmailName = 'EMAIL_NAME' 
AND j2.JourneyName = 'JOURNEY_NAME'
AND Status = 'Unsubscribed'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  s.SubscriberKey as EMAIL_ADDRESS
, s.jobid
, s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
, sub.EmailAddress
, j.EmailName
, j2.JourneyName
, j2.VersionNumber
FROM _Sent s 
join _Job j on s.jobid = j.jobid
join _Subscribers sub on s.SubscriberKey = sub.SubscriberKey
join _JourneyActivity j1 on j1.JourneyActivityObjectID = s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID 
join _Journey j2 on j2.VersionID = j1.VersionID
WHERE j.EmailName = 'EMAIL_NAME' 
AND j2.JourneyName = 'JOURNEY_NAME'
AND sub.Status = 'Unsubscribed'
```

You had `s.SubscriberKey = sub.SubscriberID` while they are not the same IDs.

Also, `sub.` alias was missing in the `Status` field.

Comment: Thanks Zuzanna, that looks fine. My querying is system erroring. I think this is because I am querying multiple data views, so I will look breaking it down to multiple queries.

Comment: What error does it give you now? I tested it in query studio and worked fine for me

Comment: The error is "Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int". Normally, this type of error is associated with how one of the tables is designed. However, in this case we are pulling from data views.

Comment: Have you checked if the data types in your target DE match the data types in the data views?

Comment: It seems to be working now! Nothing changed beside logging in and out of SFMC. Thanks as always :)